# How to get page number count from oDoc Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to extract the page number from where a word is find. This is my current code:

```
Sub LocateSearchItem()
    Dim shtSearchItem As Worksheet
    Dim shtExtract As Worksheet
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurrentRowShtSearchItem As Long
    Dim CurrentRowShtExtract As Long
    Dim myPara As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    WordNotOpen = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Moham\Desktop\mydocx.docx")   
    Set shtSearchItem = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=shtSearchItem
End If
Set shtExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
LastRow = shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows(shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 2 To LastRow
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range
    With oRange.Find
        .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShtSearchItem, 1).Text
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        While oRange.Find.Execute = True
            oRange.Select

'This is the important part


            myPara = oDoc.Range(0, oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
            
            CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1).Value = .Text
            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 2).Value = myPara
            shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 3) = oDoc.Paragraphs(myPara).Range
            




            oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Wend
    End With
Next CurrRowShtSearchItem

If WordNotOpen Then
    oWord.Quit
End If


Set oWord = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing

Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    If WordNotOpen Then
        oWord.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

I am not able to find the page number element in oDoc.
How to get the page number of that paragraph? Also currently the paragraph counts even the titles. Is there a way to avoid counting titles as well as counting blank paragraphs?

For example, currently it says the "Hello daniel" to be in para 5.

```
HELLO   ---> Format Title
hi there all    ----> para 2
this is your professor  ----->para 3
                     -------> para 4
say hello to him        ------------->para 5
Hello Daniel --------------> para 6
```

It should actually say para 4 because the first line is title and there is one empty para above "say hello to him" para.

Comment: You can get the page number from the range.Information property.  You will have to write custom code if you need to count only paragraphs with outline level 9.

Comment: To add on to freeflow's comment - It will be something like `Range.Information(3)`, the enumeration is `wdActiveEndPageNumber` but since you are using late binding, you can use the value of it (3). [Range.Information documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.information), [WdInformation enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation)

Comment: @RaymondWu is there a way to get the number of paragraphs on the page? Like it might be para 13 in whole document but I need it to be like para 2 of page 3. You go the idea?

Comment: @derik0003 Maybe, you can use [GoTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.goto) to set your range to the beginning of page #, so you will set your `Range` at the start of the page and end of the found paragraph and return `Paragraphs.Count`. The problem is you have to create a logic that exclude title and empty paragraph as mentioned in your question

Comment: @freeflow thank you for your help. One more thing, you said that the paragraph with outline level 9. Where is this property given? Is it in range.information itself?

Comment: The property you need is `Paragraph.OutlineLevel`, and you need to look for paragraphs with an outline level of Body Text, the numeric value for which is 10, not 9.